# How can I find out what is setting my windows 7 NTFS partition's dirty bit all the time?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, ntfs

My windows 7 machine's dirty flag is being set all the time on my primary partition. It is a RAID-0 striped drive which have been working for the last year without a glitch. The last few weeks every time that I reboot the dirty flag is set and chkdsk runs without finding anything to fix.

This started happening about a month ago but I can't think of anything which changed at that time to cause this to happen.

How can I out what is causing this dirty flag to be set?

Comment: it is possible this is due to one or more of the drives in the raid array reporting through SMART that they are not healthy. Windows may simply be proactively checking the array to ensure the file structure is secure. alternatively, is windows shutting down properly when you reboot?

Comment: AFAIK Windows shuts down cleanly every time before this happens. I did a full chkdsk /f /r c: and it ran most of yesterday. Didn't report anything but I'll know when I reboot again in a day or three.

Comment: after the full chkdsk I rebooted for the first time yesterday and sure as hell the dirty flag was set again

Answer (score 0):

Run the manufacturers diagnostics on each of the drives, see the third post in this thread

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/How-to-test-RAM-and-HDD-Hard-Drive/td-p/301638

.

Comment: For some reason there's something wrong with my SMART. That speccy app can't give me any SMART info and it can't determine the harddrive manufacturer either :/ Don't know what to make of this.

Comment: Smart resides on the hard drive, it could be a defective controller board on the hard drive itself.